# How can I get the current users of a particular user flair using PRAW?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to get all the users that are currently making use of a particular flair. Is there a way to get the users of a flair if I have the flair object itself?

I saw that others did this by accessing the 'user' key in the `flair` object like so: `flair['user']`, but those posts were made years ago and I guess PRAW stopped supporting this method somewhere along the line, because when I try this, I get this error: `KeyError: flair['user']`

I've looked at the PRAW documentation and haven't seen any way of getting the current users of a flair, so I wonder if anyone has any suggestions I can check out.

I've thought of just iterating over every post and getting their author_flair_text attribute, but that's too slow and doesn't even fit in my overall code.

This is the code:

```
def clearFlairsFromPreviousHolders(subreddit):
    userList = []

    for flair in subreddit.flair.templates:
        if "Poster for Week" in flair['text']:
            print(flair['user'])

    subreddit.flair.update(userList, text='')
```

I'm trying to clear the flairs of all users that are currently using the flairs that contain a certain keyword.

I expected to get a list of users who were using the flairs at the time, but instead I got a KeyError.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Got the reason lol**

Looks like `flair['user']` only works when you generate flairs with `subreddit.flair(limit=None)`, as opposed to `subreddit.flair.templates`, which is what I used.

Yeah, pretty easy fix but it's weird that I couldn't find that in the documentation. Or maybe I just didn't look hard enough.